# MS Chart and NaN

Tags: c#, mschart

I'm using MS Chart with C# and I'm having issues when I try to retrieve almost any meta values from the chart, all I am getting is NaN.  Couple of examples...

```
void chart_CursorPositionChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
{
            double selectStart = e.NewSelectionStart;
            double selectEnd = e.NewSelectionEnd;
}

e.NewSelectionStart and e.NewSelectionEnd both show NaN for their values.
```

Another example...

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum
```

is also NaN.  However, if I set it to a value the chart properly reflects it.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please learn the correct markup to format your code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might not be properly initializing `chart.ChartAreas[0]`: Have you set `Cursor.IsUserSelectionEnabled` to true?

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsSelectionEnabled = true;
```

If you haven't enabled user selecting then the event will still fire when a user clicks and moves the mouse, but a selection won't take place.

As for

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum == Double.NaN
```

This means that the chart will manage the margin itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the data provided by CursorEventArgs like you currently are, do this:

```
void chart_CursorPositionChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
{
            double selectStart = chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX.SelectionStart;
            double selectEnd = chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX.SelectionEnd;

}
```

I experienced the same problem as you today, and this solved it for me. I dont know why the CursorEventArg data returns an NaN though